# How to make self-modify Excel workbook in shared folder with read-only permissions?

Tags: excel, vba, self-modifying

I made a workbook with VBA which is stored at shared folder of my employer. Employees can open this folder and workbook, but only as read-only.
User at this workbook works with several macros and I need to count number of starts these macros and store this data somewhere. In the best way, it will be stored in the workbook itself. But they do not have rights to modify the workbook, so they cannot save it even if I will try do it automatically as part of macro.
So what I need, is to find a way, how to make this workbook self editing (or auto-saving).

I found two possible ways, but they do not work at this scenario:

- Because the file is opened just in read-only mode, I cannot save it directly. I even cannot use save-as and rewrite that file, because I haven't rights to editing it in that folder.
- I found a way, where is new document in PC repository and the workbook saves data in that file and this file must be saved somewhere, where it could be editable. But I do not know networking enough to find a save place where I will make this file and even more, I am not sure, how will HQ looks at this type of activity.

I would prefer to count it in the file, but from MS support I get, that I cannot save it, just rewrite, which is impossible if I have not rights for that. So my question is, is there any save way how to count it or store data somewhere else?

Comment: If there's read-only access, then you *have* to save it somewhere else.

Comment: Write out to a text file stored in a different folder, and give your users write access to that location.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, without getting write-permissions fixed for your users, it can't be done.  You should work with your network administrator to explain your requirements for the users.

Alternatively, you need to find a place where every user DOES have write-access, then design the script to save-as to that location.  It all comes down to permissions.